How can I remove a system setting that causes snapd to segfault on startup?
I've tried setting a kernel commandline parameter through snapd, which is apparently the way we do this now:
sudo snap set system system.kernel.cmdline-append="initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init"

snapd now refuses to start at all.  Every start results in an immediate crash.  Details below but it appears to be caused by the kernel commandline setting.  Is there a way to unset this that doesn't involve having the snapd daemon running?
It leaves this in the journal:
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: Started snapd.service - Snap Daemon.
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7095, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7096, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7097, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7098, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7099, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7100, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7101, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7102, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7103, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7104, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7105, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7106, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7107, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7108, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7109, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7110, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7111, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7112, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7113, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7114, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7115, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7116, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7117, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Got notification message from PID 7118, but reception only permitted for main PID 6841
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x654440d46d7f]
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: goroutine 196 [running]:
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.validateCmdlineParamsAreAllowed(0x654440e699bb?, {0x65444127c720?, 0xc0005ba738?}, {0xc0002b4640, 0x31})
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore/kernel.go:67 +0x3f
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.validateCmdlineAppend({0x65444127b570?, 0xc0005b87b0})
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore/kernel.go:99 +0x35b
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.(*withStateHandler).validate(0xc0006126a0, {0x74935c704038?, 0xc0005b87b0})
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:110 +0x42
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.applyHandlers({0x74935db662b0, 0xc0003dc078}, {0x65444127b570, 0xc0005b87b0}, {0xc000618400, 0x1c, 0xc000>
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:169 +0x303
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.Run({0x74935db662b0?, 0xc0003dc078?}, {0x65444127b570?, 0xc0005b87b0?})
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:148 +0x3c
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate.Init.func1(0x654441153120?)
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configmgr.go:82 +0x30
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).runHook(0xc0004f6c80, 0xc0001ff2d0, 0xc00032ae00?, 0xc00032ae00, 0x0?)
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:399 +0x5d1
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).runHookForTask(0xc0004f6c80, 0x654440e46cdf?, 0xa?, 0x0?, 0x400?)
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:313 +0x6d
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).doRunHook(0x0?, 0xc0005bf2c0, 0x65444056898f?)
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:265 +0x10c
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/state.(*TaskRunner).run.func1()
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/state/taskrunner.go:220 +0xaa
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: gopkg.in/tomb%2ev2.(*Tomb).run(0xc00035aeb0, 0x6d6f6e672f75746e?)
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         gopkg.in/tomb.v2@v2.0.0-20161208151619-d5d1b5820637/tomb.go:163 +0x2b
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]: created by gopkg.in/tomb%2ev2.(*Tomb).Go in goroutine 160
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 snapd[6841]:         gopkg.in/tomb.v2@v2.0.0-20161208151619-d5d1b5820637/tomb.go:159 +0xe5
Jun 10 09:46:52 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

And slightly more detail in syslog:
2024-06-10T09:46:55.087549+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: will consider standby after: 5s
2024-06-10T09:46:55.087583+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: activation done in 2.546s
2024-06-10T09:46:55.088913+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: Next refresh scheduled for 2024-06-10T16:42:19+01:00.
2024-06-10T09:46:55.151959+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 141 ("X-GNOME-FullName=Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor") in source of desktop file "inkscape_inkscape.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.151979+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 262 ("TryExec=inkscape") in source of desktop file "inkscape_inkscape.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.152100+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 154 ("X-MultipleArgs=false") in source of desktop file "firefox_firefox.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.152340+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 253 ("TryExec=gimp-2.10") in source of desktop file "gimp_gimp.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.152356+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 1 ("Encoding=UTF-8") in source of desktop file "thunderbird_thunderbird.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.152389+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: ignoring line 108 ("X-MultipleArgs=false") in source of desktop file "thunderbird_thunderbird.desktop"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.305924+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: Running task 1566 on Doing: Run configure hook of "core" snap
2024-06-10T09:46:55.333013+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: kernel option: validating system.kernel.cmdline-append="initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init"
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335192+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335241+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x64aaf31a27c5]
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335250+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: goroutine 242 [running]:
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335256+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.validateCmdlineParamsAreAllowed(0x64aaf32c4b36?, {0x64aaf38990f8?, 0xc00041d800?}, {0xc0006c0cc0, 0x31})
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335263+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configcore/kernel.go:67 +0x45
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335272+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.validateCmdlineAppend({0x64aaf3898648?, 0xc00017fc80})
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335278+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configcore/kernel.go:99 +0x352
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335284+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.(*withStateHandler).validate(0xc00043da20, {0x7ca9919a41c0?, 0xc00017fc80})
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335290+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:110 +0x46
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335296+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.applyHandlers({0x7ca9919a5960, 0xc000312dc8}, {0x64aaf3898648, 0xc00017fc80}, {0xc0000da800, 0x1c, 0xc0008d3a58?})
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335303+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:169 +0xf4
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335309+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate/configcore.Run({0x7ca9919a5960?, 0xc000312dc8?}, {0x64aaf3898648?, 0xc00017fc80?})
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335315+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configcore/runwithstate.go:148 +0x45
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335320+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/configstate.Init.func1(0x64aaf3775d40?)
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335326+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/configstate/configmgr.go:82 +0x3a
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335332+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).runHook(0xc0006ee0f0, 0xc0002c7340, 0xc000371680?, 0xc000371680, 0x0?)
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335347+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:399 +0x5f1
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335353+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).runHookForTask(0xc0006ee0f0, 0x64aaf32a3304?, 0xa?, 0xc0003ae568?, 0x64aaf2974a1d?)
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335362+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:313 +0x76
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335367+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/hookstate.(*HookManager).doRunHook(0x0?, 0xc000287e00, 0x64aaf29d3537?)
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335391+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/hookstate/hookmgr.go:265 +0x118
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335398+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: github.com/snapcore/snapd/overlord/state.(*TaskRunner).run.func1()
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335404+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/overlord/state/taskrunner.go:220 +0xb4
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335410+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: gopkg.in/tomb%2ev2.(*Tomb).run(0xc00057eb40, 0x68742f6572616873?)
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335418+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/vendor/gopkg.in/tomb.v2/tomb.go:163 +0x36
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335424+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: created by gopkg.in/tomb%2ev2.(*Tomb).Go
2024-06-10T09:46:55.335430+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7147]: #011/build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/vendor/gopkg.in/tomb.v2/tomb.go:159 +0xee
2024-06-10T09:46:55.336930+01:00 VSYS-LT28 snap-failure[7141]: error: snapd failed: exit status 2
2024-06-10T09:46:55.337493+01:00 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.failure.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-06-10T09:46:55.337529+01:00 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.failure.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-06-10T09:46:55.337574+01:00 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: Failed to start snapd.failure.service - Failure handling of the snapd snap.
2024-06-10T09:46:55.337640+01:00 VSYS-LT28 systemd[1]: snapd.failure.service: Consumed 10.916s CPU time.

